# How do I access an SMB Share being hosted on a Mac running OS X?

Tags: macos, terminal, network, time-machine

I'm very new to the world of Apple so pardon my ignorance & general lack of knowledge.

I only have Terminal access to a Mac which is being used for test purposes. I'm trying to share a folder that I created so I can access it from a Windows machine.

I logged in as "root" and created a folder with the following command:

```
mkdir /macshare1
```

I tried sharing with the following command:

```
sharing -s /macshare1 -S macshare1
```

Since the IP Address of the Mac is 172.16.26.193, I tried to access this machine from Windows Explorer with the following username:

```
172.16.26.193\root
```

But doing so I'm unable to view the share. I'm not sure why it fails to access the folder but can you please help me out if I've missed some command? 
I'd prefer to give read access to all users.

Comment: What error messages to you get when it fails to connect? Where did you create the share folder? If you created the folder in `/Macintosh HD/macshare1` you may need to go a little deeper and create `/Macintosh HD/Shares/macshare1` instead. I remember dimly there was a problem making shared folders at the root level of the HD.

Comment: Did you also enable File Sharing in System Preferences/Sharing?

Comment: So.. Did it work?

Answer (score 2):

This should be all you need to create an ***SMB*** share point:

```
root@host:~# sharing -a /path/directory
```

It will also be available via ***AFP & FTP*** by default.

---

Alternatively, you can specify ***SMB only*** instead, like so:

```
root@host:~# sharing -a /path/directory -s 010
```

---

Check for success by listing all share point records:

```
root@host:~# sharing -l
```

It should now be discoverable & accessible to your local network.